# A certain type of combinatorial identity, involving de Montmort numbers

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics

It would lead me too far to explain how I stumbled upon the somewhat obscure identities
$$\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} (1-m)^m m^{n-m}=(-1)^n d_n, \quad  \sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} (1-m)^{m-1} m^{n-m}=1,$$
where $d_n=n!\sum^{n}_{k=0} (-1)^k /k!$ is the $n$-th de Montmort number, when doing some algebro-geometric considerations. No doubt they are well-known to professional combinatorialists. As stated, they look rather unmotivated; surely they are special cases of a much broader class of identities. Ideally I would like to get a reference for the latter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In John Riordan's book *Combinatorial Identities*, page 21, is the formula
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(x+k)^k (y+n-k)^{n-k}=
  \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} k!\, (x+y+n)^{n-k}.$$
(There is a typo in the formula given in the book—this is the correct version.) Riordan writes, "This is usually called Cauchy's formula," but I don't know of a reference to Cauchy's work. The case $x=-1, y=-n$ is the OP's first formula.

Sections 1.5 and 1.6 of Riordan's book are devoted to Abel-type formulas.

Comment: Section 1.5 is basically the ideal reference. I thus accept this answer; your other answer is equally interesting, however, and no doubt both of the formulas I mentioned in my question can be regarded as a special case of Ryser's general formula for the permanent.

Answer (score 6):

The first formula is due to Herbert Ryser, who derived it from an inclusion-exclusion formula for the permanent of a matrix. It can be found in his book *Combinatorial Mathematics,* Mathematical Association of America, Washington, D. C., 1963. I don't have my copy available so I can't tell you exactly where in the book it is. A proof of Ryser's formula and a generalization to Latin rectangles can be found in
Peter G. Doyle, *The number of Latin rectangles*, arXiv:math/0703896 [math.CO], https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703896, section 3.

Comment: I think it's (4.15) on page 28 at the end of Section 4: The permanent, of Chapter 1. It looks a little different in the book: $$D_n=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}(-1)^r{n\choose r}(n-r)^r(n-r-1)^{n-r}$$

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to generalize these identities. [Abel's binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_binomial_theorem) generalizes the second one as follows

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a(a-kt)^{k-1}(b+kt)^{n-k}=(a+b)^n$$

Your identity follows by specializing $a=1, b=0, t=1$. Using Abel's binomial theorem and some umbral calculus you can generalize the fist identity as well. This is done in the paper ["$\lambda$-factorials of $n$"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.1339) by Sun and Zhuang.

Define the polynomials
$$D_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}d_{n-k}x^k.$$
Then the following Abel type identity holds
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(x+k)^k(y-k-1)^{n-k}=D_n(x+y)$$
Your identity follows by specializing $x=y=0$.

Answer (score 4):

The second identity is the special case $x=1$, $z=1$, $y=0$ of Abel's generalization of the binomial theorem, as stated in *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 2, Exercise 5.31(c). This identity states that
$$ (x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x(x-kz)^{k-1}(y+kz)^{n-k}. $$

Comment: Many thanks for pointing out this result - I should have been aware of it.